# Tensorflow Logging: TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am running a deep learning model using Tensorflow on Windows 11. I have installed all the driver requirements from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Q6SM_usn84). The code runs but it brings this:

```
TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
```

Does this mean the tensorflow uses cpu instead of gpu?

Here is the taskmanager gpu usage during code runtime:
[image: Taskmanager gpu usage]

Comment: is this helpful?: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_tensor_float_32_execution

Comment: Yes it provides some insight, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

TensorFloat32 is basically a numerical format exclusively in Ampere GPU or Later. TensorFloat32 consist of Range of FP32 and Precision of FP16. TensorFloat32 is automatically enabled in Ampere GPU or later.

For more detail, you can visit: https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2020/05/14/tensorfloat-32-precision-format/

Comment: And what do you mean by Ampere GPU?